# differnet parameter result in different results while import C++ dll in C#

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport

I'm trying to import dll coded in C++ in C#. What's really stange and bothers me is that: different parameter count or type in C#, and I get different result.  Let me explain in detail.

Test Code in C++:

```
FUN_API BOOL WriteUPS()
{
    //The maximum size of an output report.
    const unsigned short int    MAXREPORTSIZE = 65;
    BOOL    bWriteSuccess = FALSE;   

    DWORD   BytesWritten = 0;
    CHAR    OutputReport[MAXREPORTSIZE];
    ULONG   Result;
    CString strBytesWritten = "";

    memset(OutputReport,'\0',MAXREPORTSIZE);
//The first byte is the report number.
OutputReport[0]=0;

//memcpy(OutputReport+1,Command,MAXREPORTSIZE-1);


OutputReport[1]=0x41;
OutputReport[2]=0x51;

Result = WriteFile 
    (ReadHandle, 
    OutputReport, 
    Capabilities.OutputReportByteLength, 
    &BytesWritten,
    (LPOVERLAPPED) &HIDOverlapped); 



Result = WaitForSingleObject 
    (hEventObject, 
    500);

switch (Result)
{
case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
    {
        bWriteSuccess = TRUE;
        break;
    }
case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
    {
        //Cancel the Write operation.
        Result = CancelIo(ReadHandle);
        bWriteSuccess = FALSE;
        break;
    }
default:
    {
        bWriteSuccess = FALSE;
        break;
    }
}

ResetEvent(hEventObject);

if(!bWriteSuccess)
    return FALSE;
else
    return TRUE;
}
```

Calling function in C#:

```
private const string DLLPath = @"C:/Test/USBTest/USBComm.dll";
  [DllImport(DLLPath,CharSet=CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern bool WriteUPS();
```

It works well and I can see good data transfer ("AQ") from PC to USB device.

However, if I modify like following while the other part remains:

```
//Modification in C++
FUN_API BOOL WriteUPS(char Command[])  
//Modification in C#
public static extern bool WriteUPS(char[] command);
```

Then I got error data (not "AQ").

Again, if I modify like following while the other part remains:

```
//Modification in C++
FUN_API BOOL WriteUPS(char* Command)  
//Modification in C#
 public static extern bool WriteUPS(string command);
```

Then I got some different error data (not "AQ").

Could anyone please help to explain ?

Comment: You aren't showing all the code. Show a cut down minimal MCVE, and then we have a question

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
//Modification in C++
FUN_API BOOL WriteUPS(char* Command)  

 //Modification in C#
 public static extern bool WriteUPS(string command);
```

in this way the string is `\0` terminated automatically. If you use

```
FUN_API BOOL WriteUPS(char Command[])
```

then you'll have to make sure the last character of the string is `\0`

Then

```
memcpy(OutputReport+1,Command,strlen(Command));
```

You were copying too many bytes. The right number of bytes to copy is `strlen(Command)`

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I don't think it's the root cause.  Actually, in order to make sure that this issue doesn't come from the "memcpy" function, I don't use this function in my test code( you can check my code again).  Do you have any other idea about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I advise that you can pass two parameters to this method. One is the data and second is length. This way you will know exactly how many characters to copy from the parameter.

Other than that are you sure your command length will not be more than 65? You should probably not fix it so that any data size can be sent

Put a '\0' at end of length passed. It will work both for char array and pointer versions.

Comment: The problem is that, actually , In my tests, I did not copy anything from the parameter. The thing is with the same code in C++, the only difference is 1. FUN_API BOOL WriteUPS() 2. FUN_API BOOL WriteUPS(char Comamnd[]). Note that, the parameter is not used in code. Then, when I try to call them in C#, use the expression 1. public static extern bool WriteUPS();2. public static extern bool WriteUPS(char[] command); corresponding to C++ code.  However, the final result is different.  Please help

Comment: Have you tried passing null to the method? Try this as this will reduce any chance of passing some allocated or unallocated buffer that may be causing this problem. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Yes, I have tried to pass no parameter to this method (As you can see in the codes of FUN_API BOOL WriteUPS()). If no paremeter , it works well. With parameter of char[] or char* , even if I do nothing with the parameter, the function goes wrong.

Comment: I meant pass a null value from C# and see if it is different. Other than this I advise: you place a log entry in code so that you know where it goes wrong. I am sure aka buffer allocation is failing. This log should give you insight on where did it break.